# Split text pairs into separate columns

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have the following table in OpenOffice Calc:

### Column 1

(Col1 Row1) jacket - White
(Col1 Row2) pants - Blue
(Col 1 Row3) Belt- Black
(Col1 Row4) jacket - Black
(Col1 Row5) pants - White
(Col 1 Row6) Belt- Blue
etc etc....

What I am trying to do is separate all the colours into a separate column (eg column 2) and leave all the items in place in column 1.

I have tried using the 'Find' and 'Replace' feature which is fine for removing the colours but I can't find a way to move those colours into another column. 
I have looked at EXACT, FILTER, LEFT and RIGHT Functions but none of these seem to fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that in your table the items and colors are separated by a hyphen, if that is the separator then one solution could be the following.

You can use the FIND function to get the position of the hyphen in the string and feed that into the LEFT formula to get everything to the left of it.  So if your first string is in cell A1 then the formula LEFT(A1;FIND("-";A1;1)-1) should get you the item.

To get the color you can use the same principle with the RIGHT formula but instead of using the result of FIND directly you'll want to subtract it from the total length of the string to get the right position.  So in this case the formula RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("-";A1;1)) should get you the color.

In both cases there is the issue leading and trailing spaces that can appear so I'd recommend wrapping both in a TRIM function.  So my final recommendations would be the following

### Formula to get item

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1;FIND("-";A1;1)-1))
```

### Formula to get color

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("-";A1;1)))
```